# updating CDATA in xml

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

i have xml file which contains CDATA

i need to update the CDATA as like in this example.

i am modifying "span" here

```
<elements>
    <![CDATA[-div[id|dir|class|align|style],-span[class|align]]]>
  </elements>
```

should be updated as

```
<elements>
    <![CDATA[-div[id|dir|class|align|style],-span[class|align|style]]]>
  </elements>
```

i am using framework 2.0.. how to do this using xmldocument.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to extract the cdata as a regular string, then adjust it using normal string operations (or a regex) before re-inserting as cdata.  That is the nature of cdata sections.

Comment: That is the nature of text nodes. It doesn't matter if they are expressed using CDATA or not.

Answer (score 5):

Just fetch the `XmlCDataSection` and change the `Value` property. Here's an example which admittedly uses LINQ to find the CData section, but the principle of changing it would be the same:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = 
@"<elements>
    <![CDATA[-div[id|dir|class|align|style],-span[class|align]]]>
</elements>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlCDataSection cdata = doc.DocumentElement
                                   .ChildNodes
                                   .OfType<XmlCDataSection>()
                                   .First();
        cdata.Value = "-div[id|dir|class|align|style],-span[class|align|style]";
        doc.Save(Console.Out);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sam: Well it's up to you to implement the logic for working out what data to set. The point of my example was to demonstrate how to change the value of a CData section.

Answer (score 1):

c# 2.0

This line updates the CDATA InnerText

```
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//elements").FirstChild.Value  = 
    "-div[id|dir|class|align|style], span[class|align|style]";
```

Full code

```
string xmlPath = @"C:\yourFolder\yourFile.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlPath);
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//elements").FirstChild.Value  = 
    "-div[id|dir|class|align|style], span[class|align|style]";
xmlDoc.Save(xmlPath);
```